# Amazon MWS - change order of size variants

Tags: xml, amazon-mws

Background:
I am an Amazon seller trying to use the MWS scratchpad to submit XML feeds to change the order of size variants from alphabetical (in which case Child XSmall appears after Child Large). Amazon technical support has not been helpful.

Can somebody tell me using an xml feed how to change the order size variants are displayed on the Amazon store front from alphabetical to an order I specify, for a product with Size variants?

The product(s) already exists and was created using a flat-file, not XML. I tried submitting the following XML feed to fix the problem. The feed was accepted with no errors, but the order of the variants did not change.

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Relationship</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Relationship>
      <ParentSKU>15041304</ParentSKU>
      <Relation>
        <SKU>1504130405</SKU>
        <SortHeuristic>5</SortHeuristic>
        <Type>Variation</Type>
      </Relation>
      <Relation>
        <SKU>1504130407</SKU>
        <SortHeuristic>7</SortHeuristic>
        <Type>Variation</Type>
      </Relation>
      <Relation>
        <SKU>1504130409</SKU>
        <SortHeuristic>9</SortHeuristic>
        <Type>Variation</Type>
      </Relation>
      <Relation>
        <SKU>1504130411</SKU>
        <SortHeuristic>11</SortHeuristic>
        <Type>Variation</Type>
      </Relation>
    </Relationship>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Thanks!

(PS. I know that the size variants can be in non-alphabetical order because other Amazon seller's have achieved it somehow.)

Comment: The XML documentation from Amazon may help.  Have you submitted the parent product via XML Feed, and set it's parentage field to 'Parent', and set up the parent child variation theme to SizeColor?  Reference the following link with with additional information (page number 48, or PDF page 53 seems like it has some applicable information to get this working)  [Amazon XML Doc](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V324496426_.pdf)

Comment: The XML feed above was accepted. That means the parent product was set up as a parent; otherwise there would have been an error. The variation theme is Size, not SizeColor, as there are no Color variants for this product. The doc citation you gave has no mention of sort order for variants. It doesn't even mention the SortHeuristic tag, which I found by googling. It is in the XSD, but isn't mentioned in the paltry documentation. I haven't found an explanation anywhere what it is for, it was just named like it might be relevant.

Comment: Everything I am reading indicates that you need to create a parent product, set the VariationTheme, and then configure that Theme's attributes.  From Seller Central, that means you add the product variations by descriptive string.  The order in which the variations appear on the Seller Central website will define what order your variations are listed, thus, to modify the order of your variations being uploaded via MWS, you need to figure out how to vary your VariationTheme options.

Comment: This would most likely be related to modifying the parent object through the product feed, not using a relationship feed to assign a parent / child relationship.  Now.. interesting note, I can find no reference to variation or parentage in the product.xsd, even though it is referenced numerous times in Amazon Documentation so it may have recently moved.

Comment: Additional note, variation attributes are supposedly a sub-node of the ProductData section of the Product feed, so this would most likely be where to modify the VariationTheme attributes for the parent product.  All this info is a bit hazy, hence why it isn't going into an answer. sorry for the comment spam.

Comment: A bit more info.. you can find the category XSD's to define what Variation Theme's are valid, but they are difficult to get your hands on.  Some individuals have just requested directly from amazon.  [ProductClothing xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/ProductClothing.xsd)  [Reference to discussion on category XSDs](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2571898)